# Error Handling: Cannot place Try...catch inside if...then

Tags: vb.net, try-catch

My current assignment has me using a `try and catch` block for error handling. The code is supposed to calculate values for going over 500 to input a certain value and under 500 a different value. My problem is I don't know where to put the try and catch handling lines. If I put the try above the if statement and catch statements after  `dueLbl.Text = "your payment is " & FormatCurrency(totalDue)`
I receive `endif must match if,else must precede if`, and catch never reached. Now if I leave the try above the if statement and leave the catch at the very bottom the code will run but still wont catch anything.

```
Public Class Form1


    Private Sub calcButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles calcButton.Click

        Dim kwHour As Double
        Dim totalDue As Double
        Dim basePay As Double
        Dim overBasePay As Double


        kwHour = kwhourValue.Text

        If kwHour <= 500 Then
            totalDue = kwHour * 0.27
            dueLbl.Text = "your payment is " & FormatCurrency(totalDue)

        Else
            basePay = 500 * 0.27
            overBasePay = (kwHour - 500) * 0.55

            totalDue = basePay + overBasePay
            dueLbl.Text = "your payment is " & FormatCurrency(totalDue)
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: try/catch blocks are for exception handling NOT error handling

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it like this...

```
Private Sub calcButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles calcButton.Click
    Try
    Dim kwHour As Double
    Dim totalDue As Double
    Dim basePay As Double
    Dim overBasePay As Double


    kwHour = kwhourValue.Text

    If kwHour <= 500 Then
        totalDue = kwHour * 0.27
        dueLbl.Text = "your payment is " & FormatCurrency(totalDue)

    Else
        basePay = 500 * 0.27
        overBasePay = (kwHour - 500) * 0.55

        totalDue = basePay + overBasePay
        dueLbl.Text = "your payment is " & FormatCurrency(totalDue)
    End If
    Catch ex as Exception
        MsgBox(ex.message)
    Finally
    'Whatever you want to do...
    End Try
End Sub
```

You can't place the `Try Catch` statement in the middle of an `IF` statement. That won't end your `IF` statement properly. The code above will catch whatever error it meets along executing your code. Additionally, you can add `Finally`. Whatever code under this will get executed after it meets the error or not. Kind of like a finale code :)

Comment: Why declare variables into `Try...Catch`?

Comment: @equisde It does make a difference where to place the declarations... But in the OP's case, it doesn't make much of a difference if you put it outside TRY or inside. Now in case the declaration of variable is equated to a volatile value upon DIM, you're safer to put the declaration inside TRY.

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> Now if I leave the try above the if statement and leave the catch at the very bottom the code will run but still wont catch anything.

I'm guessing you are getting the error in

> kwHour = kwhourValue.Text

So what you can do is put the try statement before that line wrapping that line also in the try catch block. I'm assuming here that you are asked specifically to use try catch blocks only. Otherwise there are other ways to do things here. What does your assignment say exactly?

Answer (score 0):

In this way... BTW you need to convert `kwhourValue.Text` to `Double`

```
Private Sub calcButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles calcButton.Click

    Dim kwHour As Double
    Dim totalDue As Double
    Dim basePay As Double
    Dim overBasePay As Double

  Try

    If Double.TryParse(kwhourValue.Text, kwHour) Then
       ' text is convertible to Double, and kwHour contains the Double value now
    Else
       ' Cannot convert text to Double
        End Sub
    End If

    If kwHour <= 500 Then
        totalDue = kwHour * 0.27
        dueLbl.Text = "your payment is " & FormatCurrency(totalDue)
    Else
        basePay = 500 * 0.27
        overBasePay = (kwHour - 500) * 0.55
        totalDue = basePay + overBasePay
        dueLbl.Text = "your payment is " & FormatCurrency(totalDue)
    End If

  Catch ex as Exception
    MsgBox(ex.message)
  Finally
    'Whatever you want to do...
  End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: VB.NET is a kind of like a loosely typed language. You don't really need to convert kwhourValue.Text to Double if you know kwhourValue.Text is sure to have a number value. The compiler automatically converts that for you. But anyways, it's safer to convert, but not a need.